# Querying for a list of any stocks on certain conditions on Google or Yahoo finance APIs

Tags: yahoo-finance, google-finance, google-finance-api

In Google and Yahoo finance APIs, is there any way to query for a list of stock symbols that match certain conditions?

For example, getting the 10 most valuable stock symbols? I know I can retrieve the info supyling the API the concrete symbol I want to query, but is it possible to get a list of symbols that match certain conditions?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you must supply a symbol to get the stock data in yahoo finance. You can take a look at how the google ticker works with firebug and see how you can filter out certain stocks before getting the data from yahoo